# How to stop the program from getting executed after cv2.matchTemplate function does not match the template and image?

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, object-detection

I want to create an if/else in template matching method, so that I can print if there was a match or not. But whenever the function cv2.matchTemplate does not get a match it simply throws an error instead of returning some value. So how do I get it to return me an integer value so that I can use it for comparison? Basically, how do I stop it from throwing an error and instead return some value in case of no match?

The error is: cv2.error: /tmp/opencv20160107-54198-1duzac3/opencv-2.4.12/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp:251: error: (-215) img.rows >= templ.rows && img.cols >= templ.cols in function matchTemplate

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg',0)
template = cv2.imread('template.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

methods = ['cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED','cv2.TM_SQDIFF']
res=cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
if res.any():
    print "match"
else:
    print "no match"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (img.rows >= templ.rows && img.cols >= templ.cols)

This suggests that your template size is larger than the image you're trying to run the match on, so I'd try adjusting my template size first and then check their dimensions.

> Basically, how do I stop it from throwing an error and instead return some value in case of no match?

You can run the processing code itself within the `try` block, and catch the `cv2.error` [exception](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html), e.g.:

```
try:
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    if res.any():
        # do your process
except cv2.error as e: 
    # print "No match was found"
    # return something
```

Or if you prefer this variant:

```
try:
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    ok = True
except cv2.error as e: 
    ok = False      

if ok:
    # something
```

Comment: It's working perfectly but am still getting this before the output of else part: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (img.rows >= templ.rows && img.cols >= templ.cols) in matchTemplate, file /tmp/opencv20160107-54198-1duzac3/opencv-2.4.12/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp, line 251

Comment: Hi, I'm going to limit the scope of this answer to catching the exception so that it doesn't stop the flow of your program. If this works please accept this answer and post another question with details (e.g. example image file) for us to reproduce your error and come up with a fix!

Comment: But from what it looks like, it seems your template is of larger size than the image you want to run the match on

Comment: It's working perfectly. I am getting "No Match printed" along with a message about the error. How do I remove this message?